# mongodb $ causing error The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: mongodb

I’ve been trying to update the data in my mongoDB.
I want to update all products with a new productName field.

my data looks something like:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "products": [{
        "id": 0
        "productCode": "test",
        "status": "PENDING",
    },
    {
        "id": 1
        "productCode": "test",
        "status": "COMPLETE",
    }],
}
```

When I try the following. I get this error **The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.**

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  { id: "12345" },
  { $set: {
    "products.$.productName": "Name here" } 
  }
)
```

If I do account.0.productName  then it’s fine and updates. I’m not sure why $ is not working for me

```
db.customers.updateMany(
  { id: "12345" },
  { $set: {
    "products.0.productName": "Name here" } 
  }
)
```

Comment: Is `productName` a typo? Should be `productCode`?

Comment: no I wanted to add a new productName to all of my products and I wanted productCode to stay the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Positional operator is not working because you are not using the array into the `find` (first object)

If you try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k1ws2WC8Qg3) query it will work as expected because you have the position finding by `products.id`.

Otherwise, if you don't have the position into array where update, yo can't use `$` operator in this way. You need this query:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "id": "12345",
  
},
{
  "$set": {
    "products.$[].newField": "test2"
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Mongo playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9WkqHO0TBQo)

Using `$[]` you can reference the array and add the value into each object.

`$[]` docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

It says:

> The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.

That's exactly we want :)

Comment: Thank you so much J.F!!! This answer worked perfectly!!!